# EMR Hadoop does not utilize all cluster nodes

Tags: amazon-web-services, hadoop, mapreduce, emr

We are experimenting with Hadoop and processing of the Common Crawl.

Our problem is that if we create a cluster with 1 `Master` Node and 1 `Core` and 2 `Task` nodes, only one of the nodes per group will get high CPU/Network usage. 
We tried also with 2 `Core` and no `Task` nodes, but in this case also only one `Core` node was used.

Following some screenshots of the Node/Cluster monitoring. The job was running all the time (in the first two parallel map phases), and should have used most of the available CPU power, as you can see in the screenshot of the working `Task` node.
But why is the idle `Task` node not utilized?

Our hadoop job, running as an `Jar` step, has no limits for the map jobs. It consists of multiple map/reduce steps chained. The last reduce job is limited to one Reducer.

Screenshots:
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1xwABYJMJAC_B0OuVpTQ9LNSj12TtbxI1?usp=sharing

ClusterId: `j-3KAPYQ6UG9LU6`

StepId: `s-2LY748QDLFLM9`

We found the following in the System Logs of the idle Node during an other run, maybe it is an EMR problem?

```
ERROR main: Failed to fetch extraInstanceData from https://aws157-instance-data-1-prod-us-east-1.s3.amazonaws.com/j-2S62KOVL68GVK/ig-3QUKQSH7YJIAU.json?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X
```

Greetings 
Lukas

Comment: Are all the nodes data nodes? Do they have Node Managers (YARN) installed?

Comment: Added software setup screenshot to the drive. Using EMR 5.10. I think YARN is installed by default?

Comment: Do you have Ambari?, It does not default when adding new data nodes. You have to manually install the nodemanger service. Manually refers to installing via Ambari usually.

Comment: @Petro EMR doesn't typically have Ambari. AWS has its own management console

Comment: If you've limited to one reducer, only one server is used for it

Comment: @cricket_007 we have chained three jobs, only the last one is limited in the reducer number.
First we run job0. then we wait with job0.waitForCompletion(true) and run the next job after that. All jobs are declared like following Job job1 = Job.getInstance(conf, "description");
Do you see an problem in this?

Comment: And what are the keys you're generating in the map tasks? If they are all the same, then they'll also all go to one node

Comment: The keys are different. In our case domains in the common crawl.
The first job consists of two parallel maps (One over the WET and one over the WAT files). The results get then merged by an reducer. The next jobs aggregate and sort the results.

Comment: Hmm. I haven't used EMR or Common Crawl, just  stating what I've experienced with physical hadoop installs

Answer (score 0):

Late to the party, but have you tried setting these properties as part of the spark submit command.

```
--conf 'spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled=true' 
--conf 'spark.dynamicAllocation.minExecutors=<MIN_NO_OF_CORE_OR_TASK_NODES_YOU_WANT>'
```